# How to pull data from inside arrays in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

So I have a main field EmailFrom and inside it has arrays with some info of their own.

I am trying to pull this data from firestore but I am not sure how to go about it.

[image]

Here is how I am pulling data currently

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        let cityRef = db.collection("Users").doc(user);
        let getDoc = cityRef
          .get()
          .then((doc) => {
            if (!doc.exists) {
              console.log("No such document!");
            } else {
              console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
              let z = 0;
              for (z = 0; z < 5; z++) {
                let data = doc.data();
                let emailBody = data.EmailBody;
                let emailsubject = data.EmailSubject;
                let emailSubject = emailsubject[z];
                let olddate = data.EmailDate;
                let oldDate = olddate[z];
                let emailDateYear = new Date(oldDate).getFullYear();
                let emailDateMonth = new Date(oldDate).getMonth();
                let emailDateDay = new Date(oldDate).getDate();
                let emailfrom = data.EmailFrom;
                let emailFrom = emailfrom[z];
                console.log(olddate);
```

so basically I am trying to use the data.EmailFrom[arrayNumber] method to pull the data in my current setup but because this data is like further inside the array I am not sure how to access it. Tried searching online and cannot find much to help me on this one. Any help would be appreciated =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
const data = doc.data();
const address = data.EmailFrom[0].value[0].address;
```